# JQuery custom validation does not work

Tags: jquery, validation, handler, parameters

my HTML code is:

```
<select class="validateCardNotExpired" id="order_credit_card_expiration_month">
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
..........
</select>

<select class="validateCardNotExpired" id="order_credit_card_expiration_year">
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
......
</select>
```

Javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateCardNotExpired", function(value, element, params){
        alert("validate exp");
.........
    }, 'Your card has expired.');

$("#order_form").validate({
tried also:
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

    rules: {
        order_credit_card_expiration_month: {
            validateCardNotExpired: {
                month: '#order_credit_card_expiration_month',
                year: '#order_credit_card_expiration_year'
            }
        },
        order_credit_card_expiration_year: {
            validateCardNotExpired: {
                month: '#order_credit_card_expiration_month',
                year: '#order_credit_card_expiration_year'
            }
        }
    }
});

}
```

The problem is:

when I use (as recommended in every example) a handler with three parameters:

```
function(value, element, params)
```

alert does not show up (it seems that JQ validation engine encounters some exception, btw, how to catch it in this case?)

when I remove the third parameter:

```
function(value, element)
```

alert shows up.

And it seems that "rules" are ignored in any case.

What could be wrong?

Comment: need to show all of the custom validation method....  the important part is what it returns which is missing above. Post some of the form html as well. rules names must match field names, not sure that's what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the problems were because validation plugin identifies controls by name, not by id.

Comment: Did you succeed in solving this without changing the names?  I have a case where we have text fields with the same name (to map to a struts 2 String[]) but the validation won't work because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to use your function is below:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateCardNotExpired", function(value, params, element){
        alert("validate exp");
.........
    }, 'Your card has expired.');
```

Basically element should be third parameter in function.

Comment: Imagine that I've cut out any contents of this handler leaving only alert in place. In this case there is no difference in which order the parameters are passed. Actually the (assumptive) exception is not inside of this handler, but OUTSIDE of it and only number of arguments matters.

Comment: The excerpt from jquery.validate.js from the place where custom handler is called: var result = $.validator.methods[method].call(this, element.value.replace(/\r/g, ""), element, rule.parameters); So, the first parameter is value ("this" goes to handler transparently), then element and parameters.